# Picture is rotated after HTTPPost

Tags: android

I am using the necessary intents (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE etc) to take picture and video which I used HTTPPost to send to a backend server (running java servlet).

One thing i noticed is that after the image and video are sent, over at the server side it is rotated 90 degrees clockwise.

Is there any way to resolve this? i am using FileEntity class method to send the pictures and videos.

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal